# How to restrict website for SSL only on production but keep working without ssl locally

Tags: .net, ssl

I am wondering to define a configuration for ssl in a way that, on production the site works on ssl only where as I can switch to normal http on staging and locally. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This! https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/

I use it in all my websites that require ssl, can be installed from nuget and is really simple to manage just by adding a couple of lines of code in the webconfig.

By default it disables ssl in your dev environment but enabled when in production.

You can specify folders and files that shouldn't be encrypted (image folder, css etc.) reducing overhead and improving performance. It also suppresses ssl warning when switching between secure and non secure pages.

Comment: How it would know weather the site running on staging or production? Also, how could I prevent it to encrypt the static resources?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/wiki/SecuritySwitchConfigSection

The mode option can be set to On, RemoteOnly, LocalOnly, Off

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/wiki/ConfiguringPaths

You can configure paths and files in the webconfig and specify if they should be delivered securely or not.

`<add path="~/Media/" security="Ignore" />`
`<add path="~/Admin/" />`

Comment: That sounds great. I will try this out. One quick question, I have an Angular app, and I turn on the HTML5Mode and define rewrite rules in web.config. So If I want to secure my login which url is /login, will that work or require some other configuration as well?

Comment: I would assume so, I've used the URL rewriting module in IIS and also used map.routes and haven't had any problems. You can override securityswitch and handle URLs manually though, I doubt you'll need to do this. More info here https://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/wiki/DynamicEvaluation

Comment: OK, Thanks a lot. Wouldn't you mind if I ask you another simple question.. Do I need to set SSL Enabled to true by going into the properties of the project after installing this module?

Comment: No, in fact that will cause problems I believe, you also must not enable `require ssl` in IIS, the security switch module handles all of this for you. It always works pretty much out of the box unless you are doing something funky like using a non standard ssl port.